# How to reference Ghostscript DLL in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript

I'm using a C# wrapper to convert PDFs to images using Ghostscript, however i cant seem to reference the dll correctly.
I have the DLL stored in the bin folder (also don't know if that's the best place to keep it there or not)
Here's my code:

```
 byte[] fileData = null;
            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
            {
                fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
            }

    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

    Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer rasterizer = null;
    Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptVersionInfo vesion = new Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptVersionInfo(new Version(0, 0, 0), path + @"\gsdll64.dll", string.Empty, Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptLicense.GPL);
    Stream inStream = new MemoryStream(fileData);
    MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
    List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();
    using (rasterizer = new Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer())
    {
        rasterizer.Open(inStream, vesion, false);
         for (int i = 1; i <= rasterizer.PageCount; i++)
        {
            //string pageFilePath = Path.Combine(outputPath, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + "-p" + i.ToString() + ".jpg");
            int dpi = 200;
            Image img = rasterizer.GetPage(dpi, dpi, i);
            img.Save(outStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            Image img = new Image
            {
                imgByteArray = outStream.ToArray()
            };
            imageList.Add(image);
        }
         rasterizer.Close();
    }
```

I'm getting the **Ghostscript native library could not be found** error.
Here's the path I get

[image]

I think it has to do with the double / and 'file://' in the DLLPath string. And should I also specify the LipPath as well?
Any help??

Comment: is ur exe under bin\debug?

Comment: no just the DLL

Comment: Dll path doesn't look alright and that's the problem. Where did you get this "file:" prefix from? It should look like "c:\users\raeda\documents\visual s......\bin\gsdll64.dll"

Answer (score 5):

In your case you should make ghostscript dll path this way:

```
string binPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string gsDllPath = Path.Combine(binPath, Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "gsdll64.dll" : "gsdll32.dll");
```

Comment: I'm using the code like yours above, but am getting an error still. I'm using version 9.26, which is the last known bug-free GS library that can interoperate with the .NET wrapper. My error is: `Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptLibraryNotInstalledException: This managed library is running under 64-bit process and requires 64-bit Ghostscript native library installation on this machine! `

Comment: @bkwdesign something changed in native gs library and I need to adjust Ghostscript.NET to work with latest gs.

Comment: @HAJAN - good to know. My statement `last known bug-free GS library` is subjective.. all I know is that things like PageCount and the rasterization functions didn't work like I expected until I rolled back GS to this version.. maybe I should roll back further?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this does not answer the question directly, I think it's worth mentioning, because I've ran into a problem using the OP's code with Ghostscript.NET version 1.2.1 published in 2016. Here's the fix I found:

In the source code, 
Ghostscript.NET\Helpers\StreamHelper.cs:171

`n = output.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`

really should've been

`n = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`

If you're opening a stream instead of a path, without modifying the above mentioned code, you'll get empty result because the input stream did not get copied.

Reading into the code in more depth finds that the input stream is written into a temp file then read again into memory. You'll be better off just using **rasterizer.Open** by the path instead of stream, if it were a PDF file on disk to begin with.